# Applying on click/on hover functions to multiple element classes in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this code that I repeat for three different elements:

```
$container.on('click', '.item-content', function (event) {
  //some code

});

$container.on('click', '.item-content2', function (event) {
  //some code

});
```

But the same functionality of the function itself. Is there a way I can concatenate these into one  statement? Like:

```
$container.on('click', ['.item-content','.item-content2'], function (event) {
  //some code

});
```

Comment: You don't need the brackets. Use `$container.on('click', '.item-content, .item-content2', function (event) {`. The brackets shown in the [jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) means that those are optional.

Comment: but it is simply comma delimited?

Comment: @Pipeline yes, within the selector string it is comma delimited.  The same rules as CSS, so you can do `'#id, .classes, #id2 .classes-within-id2, div, [type=text], .classes > p'` -- a wide range of options, all delimited by commas.  The same thing you would do inside a jQuery element selector (e.g., `$('#someselector, .someclasses')`)

Comment: @Pipeline I've flagged your selected answer.  It is incorrect and will be misleading to anyone that stumbles upon this page.  Furthermore, I have applied a negative vote to your question.  Either the answer you are selecting is wrong, or you have not wrote the proper question.  Until the correct answer is selected, I consider your question not to be valid (and thus worth the negative points)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add multiple elements like this
HTML

```
<button class="item-content">Button 1 </button>
<button class="item-content1">Button 2 </button>
<button id="item-content2">Button 3 </button>
<button class="item-content3">Button 4 </button>
```

JS

```
$('body').on('click','.item-content,.item-content1,
              #item-content2,.item-content3',function(event){
              alert(event.target.innerHTML)
})
```

[WORKING MODEL](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/vhb726qg/3/)

NOTE: Since I am not sure about `$container` i used `body` to deletegate the event.You can make changes as required.

Hope this will be useful

Answer (score 1):

You can apply selector by comma separated like ".class1,.class2"

```
$(function(){  
      $(document).on("click",".item-content,.item-content2",function(e) {
              alert('clicked');
      });  
});
```